# SignatureDoesNotMatch when overriding STS API endpoint in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-sts

I am running Terraform in AWS region us-west-2 (Oregon) in a private VPC. Because of this I am using [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) to expose the [STS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and am overriding this endpoint in Terraform as follows:

```
provider "aws" {
  endpoints {
    sts = "https://sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this gives the following error:

```
provider.aws: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

What could be causing this issue? Applying the same Terraform code without the endpoint override in a public VPC worked as expected.

Things I have checked:

- The instance Terraform is running on is displaying the correct time (UTC)
- AWS_REGION and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION env vars are set to us-west-2
- The AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY env var I am using to authenticate (together with AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) contains only [alphanumeric characters](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/602#issuecomment-378426711)

Versions:

- `terraform version`: Terraform v0.11.13
- `terraform-provider-aws`: v2.17.0

Comment: Turn on debug first `TF_LOG=debug terraform ....`, then make sure your environment in VPC can access internet.

Comment: The problem I was having only happened when I did not have internet access, hence using VPC endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like terraform is not sanitizing the URLs before sending them to AWS:

```
provider "aws" {
  endpoints {
    sts = "https://sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" # No trailing slash
  }
}
```

Just works fine for me, while with the trailing slash it results in your error